# Trying to understand lists of dictionaries

Tags: python, list, dictionary

This is my looping code

```
for netid,email,first,last in notification_list:             # put list data in usable format
      suspend_stat_dict['netid'] = netid                        # fill dictionary
      suspend_stat_dict['email'] = email                        # fill dictionary
      suspend_stat_dict['added_day'] = added_day                # fill dictionary
      suspend_stat_dict['deletion_date'] = suspend_day          # fill dictionary
      pername_addy = convert_address(email)                     # make sure email in @uconn.edu form
      for google_data in user_emails:
         if google_data['userEmail'] == pername_addy:
            suspend_stat_dict['suspend_status'] = google_data['isSuspended']    # fill dictionary
            break
      print " each dictionary",suspend_stat_dict
      Suspended_database.append(suspend_stat_dict)              # create list of dictionaries
      print " each list", Suspended_database
      wait = raw_input("PRESS ENTER TO CONTINUE.")
```

this is the output….
I would have expected the list I am creating to be each dictionary item, not the current dictionary item duplicated ??
I don’t even understand how it is doing this….?
Any help or guidance would be awesome !

```
each dictionary {'added_day': 'August 18, 2014', 'suspend_status': 'false', 'deletion_date': 'September 10, 2014', 'email': 'deanna.tripp@gapps.uconn.edu', 'netid': 'ddt04001'}

each list [{'added_day': 'August 18, 2014', 'suspend_status': 'false', 'deletion_date': 'September 10, 2014', 'email': 'deanna.tripp@gapps.uconn.edu', 'netid': 'ddt04001'}]
PRESS ENTER TO CONTINUE.

each dictionary {'added_day': 'August 18, 2014', 'suspend_status': 'false', 'deletion_date': 'September 10, 2014', 'email': 'alexander.vitruk@gapps.uconn.edu', 'netid': 'alv13010'}

each list [{'added_day': 'August 18, 2014', 'suspend_status': 'false', 'deletion_date': 'September 10, 2014', 'email': 'alexander.vitruk@gapps.uconn.edu', 'netid': 'alv13010'}, {'added_day': 'August 18, 2014', 'suspend_status': 'false', 'deletion_date': 'September 10, 2014', 'email': 'alexander.vitruk@gapps.uconn.edu', 'netid': 'alv13010'}]
PRESS ENTER TO CONTINUE.

each dictionary {'added_day': 'August 18, 2014', 'suspend_status': 'false', 'deletion_date': 'September 10, 2014', 'email': 'simon.barres@gapps.uconn.edu', 'netid': 'sib14004'}

each list [{'added_day': 'August 18, 2014', 'suspend_status': 'false', 'deletion_date': 'September 10, 2014', 'email': 'simon.barres@gapps.uconn.edu', 'netid': 'sib14004'}, {'added_day': 'August 18, 2014', 'suspend_status': 'false', 'deletion_date': 'September 10, 2014', 'email': 'simon.barres@gapps.uconn.edu', 'netid': 'sib14004'}, {'added_day': 'August 18, 2014', 'suspend_status': 'false', 'deletion_date': 'September 10, 2014', 'email': 'simon.barres@gapps.uconn.edu', 'netid': 'sib14004'}]
PRESS ENTER TO CONTINUE.
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`suspend_stat_dict` is always the same dict, that you keep updating. Create a new dict at every iteration.

```
for netid,email,first,last in notification_list:
    suspend_stat_dict = {}
    suspend_stat_dict['netid'] = netid
    ...
```

Comment: thank you, did not realize i need to re-initialize a new dict. I will try that. -ALF

Comment: thanx Hugo that worked !!
I figured out that i was filling my list with pointers to the same memory location, causing each element in the list to be the same dict, which will always be the lastest data i filled with it. Case Closed.  -ALF

Comment: just figured out how to accept answer...jeeze, not intuitive. i can't upvote as i figured out i need at least 15 of a reputation. so i am done i think. -ALF